# How to remove certain set of strings from a column output via pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to remove certain strings from a data-frame column, just would like to know how to achieve that in a better way , one way is with multiple `replace` but i want to avoid that.

### Raw_Data

```
ctflex08 | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) server ntp-tichmond minpoll 4 maxpoll 10\nserver ntp-tichmond-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10\nserver 127.127.1.0
ctfclx806 | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) server ntp-mary.example.com
ctfclx802 | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) server ntp-mary.example.com
ti-goyala | SUCCESS | rc=0 | (stdout) server ntp-tichmond minpoll 4 maxpoll 10\nserver ntp-tichmond-b minpoll 4 maxpoll 10
```

### Data-frame Structure:

```
import pandas as pd
matchObj = ['(stdout)', 'server', 'minpoll', 'maxpoll' ]

df = pd.read_csv('ntp_server.txt', sep="|" , names=['Linux_Hosts', 'Host_Dist_version'])

df['Host_Dist_version'] =  df['Host_Dist_version'].replace("server", '',regex=True).replace("minpoll", '',regex=True)
print(df)
```

### Current Output:

```
                      Linux_Hosts                                  Host_Dist_version
ctflex08      SUCCESS        rc=0    (stdout)  ntp-tichmond  4 maxpoll 10\n ntp-ti...
ctfclx806     SUCCESS        rc=0                      (stdout)  ntp-mary.example.com
ctfclx802     SUCCESS        rc=0                      (stdout)  ntp-mary.example.com
ti-goyala     SUCCESS        rc=0    (stdout)  ntp-tichmond  4 maxpoll 10\n ntp-ti...
```

### Expected Output:

```
Linux_Hosts               Host_Dist_version
ctflex08                  ntp-tichmond  ntp-tichmond-b
ctfclx806                 ntp-mary.example.com
ctfclx802                 ntp-mary.example.com
ti-goyala                 ntp-tichmond ntp-tichmond-b
```

Is there a efficient way to Just pick the required strings and rest remove or mask them, eg `['ntp-mary', 'ntp-tichmond', 'ntp-tichmond-b']`  just see these list values and pick them only and leave the rest.

While replacing the some special chars and strings its not working like..

`SUCCESSS` treated as a keyword and `\n` also not being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('ntp_server.txt', sep="|" , names=['Linux_Hosts','Status','RC','Host_Dist_version'])
pattern = r'(ntp+[^\s]+)'
df['Host_Dist_version'] = df['Host_Dist_version'].str.findall(pattern).str.join(' ')
df = df.drop(['Status','RC'], axis =1)
print(df)
```

Resulted Output:

```
  Linux_Hosts            Host_Dist_version
0   ctflex08   ntp-tichmond ntp-tichmond-b
1  ctfclx806          ntp-mary.example.com
2  ctfclx802          ntp-mary.example.com
3  ti-goyala   ntp-tichmond ntp-tichmond-b
```

Explanation: pattern is the regex which matches a sub-string containing word `'ntp'` and captures everything until next space (which I think is the requirement), if you don't want to capture anything after the `.` then use `(ntp+[^\s.]+)` regex.

Also I created the DataFrame with 4 columns as the separator `'|'` suggests that there are 4 columns in text file, you can later drop 'Status' and 'RC' if not need them, hope this helps.

Comment: Thansk Manojk but i'm looking for the expected output.

Comment: Can you explain in bit detail, what are the difference between the solution and expected?